# Cognito own domain login page is blank

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I've transferred my domain name to Route53 to make life easier, I've created my SSL certificate for my domain and I've told Cognito to use my own domain name with the auth. subdomain but when I go to auth.mydomain.co.uk the page is blank and there are a lot of errors in the browser console, not sure what I've done wrong. Console logs -

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://auth.mydomain.co.uk/null/null/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'https://auth.mydomain.co.uk/null/null/css/cognito-login.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

jquery-3.4.1.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
amazon-cognito-advanced-security-data.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

jquery-3.4.1.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
(index):120 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index):120

/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'https://auth.mydomain.co.uk/null/null/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'https://auth.mydomain.co.uk/null/null/css/cognito-login.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: The path `https://auth.mydomain.co.uk/null/null/css/bootstrap.min.css` is correct? You have your css file in a folder named `null\null` ?

Comment: Well it’s on AWS Cognito we to use my own domain name as the url for the login page so I have no access to the files allAWS gave me was an alias record for the Route53 DNS

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out you have to include parameters in the URL such as the example below.

https://YOUR_CUSTOM_DOMAIN/login?client_id=APP_CLIENT_ID&response_type=token&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin+email+openid&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URLk

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was that I had not fully configured Cognito. Going to the App client settings, I noticed at the bottom that it said the Hosted UI Flow was not enabled because I needed to select at least one OAuth client. I selected "Authorization Code Grant" and "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin". Once I had done this the UI worked as expected.